# How to remove the padding around a Salesforce Lightning Community page?

Tags: community, css, custom-theme-layout

When you editing the community page from SFDC, even though you configure the page width to be max, any of the content section () will have padding from top, right, bottom and left which is 12px.
[image]

Is there a way to override the div class like .siteforceSldsOneColLayout .siteforceContentArea .slds-col--padded .contentRegion .comm-layout-column from the above screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override the community CSS. More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm).

[image]